# Webcodecamjs-QR code scanning Library not working in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

I want a mobile page to scan QR-codes and display it's content.
This is the page:
https://ndvibes.com/demo/TicketSystem/check (index.html)

Very weird, it's working on Firefox (Linux), but not in Safari (iOS 11.4 /iPhone 6).

I thought the library I used didn't supported Safari, or Safari restricted
it because of security reasons, but the [demo](https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/) of the [library](https://github.com/andrastoth/webcodecamjs) is working just fine on iPhone!

So it Safari seems to be supported, and it doesn't block it, because it's working in the demo...

I have no clue on how to fix this.
Safari asks for permission to access the camera, when granted, it just does not display the camera-content.
I also checked the settings of Safari, but didn't saw anything disabled that could block the webcam-video to show.

**Edit:** This code doesn't seem to work on Android either, very weird, the demo is working on desktop and mobile, and my own code is working on desktop, but doesn't work on mobile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To Use on Apple devices you have to make sure:**

**1-** You must use https, for the protocol http does not work.

**2-** You must use Safari because in Apple, the other browsers do not have permission or access to some javascript things.

**3-** must use some version so you can use both cameras.

---

**Problem:** I thought the library I used didn't supported Safari, or Safari restricted it because of security reasons, but the demo of the library is working just fine on iPhone!

---

**Reason:** I have gone through with [`your webcodecamjs.js`](https://ndvibes.com/demo/TicketSystem/check/js/webcodecamjs.js) and compared with [`demo webcodecamjs.js`](https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/js/webcodecamjs.js).I found that there are some differences in these files.May be lib-code taken from git and actual demo lib-code are diffrent.

**Solution:** Simply replace [`your webcodecamjs.js`](https://ndvibes.com/demo/TicketSystem/check/js/webcodecamjs.js) with [`demo webcodecamjs.js`](https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/js/webcodecamjs.js) and it should work.

---

**EDIT**

**Note:** You have to start the camera by event trigger as Safari doesn't allow Autoplay.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it working now, also had to add a start-button because Safari doesn't allow Autoplay; also in the demo I can use the back-camera, in my demo only the front. How to allow it to use the back-camera?

Comment: I started a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554406/using-back-camera-in-webcodecam-qr